# How can I manipulate include_once string?

Tags: php

I have a value from a dB call: `$state = $data['state'];` and lest say the value is `'AK'`.
Then I am including an `option` list like so

> ```
> ob_start();
> include_once('states.html');
> $str = ob_get_clean();
> ```

states.html looks like this

```
<option value='AK'>AK</option>
<option value='AL'>AL</option>
<option value='AR'>AR</option>
...
```

Since my return dB call is `'AK'`, how can I manipulate `$str` so that the output of

> ```
> ob_start();
> include_once('states.html');
> $str = ob_get_clean();
> ```

looks like

```
<option value='AK' selected='selected'>AK</option>
<option value='AL'>AL</option>
<option value='AR'>AR</option>
...
```

jQuery has `.filter` and I am trying to do something similar using php
ex:
    `$('[name=state] option').filter(function() { 
    var stateCaps = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
        return ( state == stateCaps);
    }).prop('selected', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a str_replace to add the "selected" attribute:

```
echo str_replace('>'.$state.'<', ' selected="selected">'.$state.'<', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = str_replace("value='" . $state ."'","value='" . $state ."' selected='selected'",$str);
```

Finds where the value has the state you are looking for, and adds on the selected portion.

Answer (score 1):

Change states.html to a PHP file and implement a loop

```
$states = array('AK', 'AL', ...); // etc

$state_html = '';
foreach ($states as $state) {
   $state_html .= sprintf('<option%s>%s</option>', $data['state'] === $state ? ' selected' : '', $state);
}

echo $state_html;
```